# Appending in a For-Loop v. List Comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm confused about why two different bits of code that ought to be doing the same thing (at least when I run it through my mind).  I've got three lists of values, called `snr`, `m1_inj`, and `m2_inj`, and I'm trying to remove all non-unique values from each list.

I can't use the numpy `uniqueify`, or whatever it's called, because that changes the order of the values, which I can't do, since the values in each list are associate with the values in the same position in the other lists.  Note that the values are numerical estimations to about 7 significant digits, so there's a negligible probability that two numbers in the final list would be identical.  Here are the two ways I've tried this:

method #1:

```
snr = [snr[i] for i in xrange(len(snr)) if snr[i] not in snr[:i]]
m1_inj = [m1_inj[i] for i in xrange(len(m1_inj)) if m1_inj[i] not in m1_inj[:i]]
m2_inj = [m2_inj[i] for i in xrange(len(m2_inj)) if m2_inj[i] not in m2_inj[:i]]
```

method #2:

```
for i in xrange(len(m1_inj)-1):
        if m1_inj[i+1] != m1_inj[i]:
                new_m1.append(m1_inj[i+1])
for i in xrange(len(m2_inj)-1):
        if m2_inj[i+1] != m2_inj[i]:
                new_m2.append(m2_inj[i+1])
for i in xrange(len(snr)-1):
        if snr[i+1] != snr[i]:
                new_snr.append(snr[i+1])
```

Almost every time, the first method worked properly, but once in a blue moon, one of the lists has one too few items.  These lists all have the same number of unique values.  However, I changed the code to the second method, and it resolved my issues.  Can anyone think of any reason why this might be?  Let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Comment: Your code is far from equivalent; in one you test against `snr[:i]` (everything so far) while in the other you only test the *previous element*.

Comment: Take `[1, 3, 1, 3]`; your first version would not add the second `3`, your second version would. Your second version also entirely ignores the first value.

Comment: In any case, your code looks like an in-efficient method to [remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order).

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, but I'm stupendously surprised that there would be any duplicates.

Comment: Your first method works, albeit in a very inefficient manner. If you see a duplicate after that method has run, you don't have a duplicate, only something that *looks a lot* like a duplicate, but the two values won't have an equal value.

Comment: If your second method 'works' for that then that's only because it always ignores the first value.